# Is it possible to define substitution rules on edges instead of nodes [Wolfram Physics]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, wolfram-physics

I have a small question about the way substitutions work in the Wolfram Physics project, which might be a general question about how to add edges between nodes and edges.

Running a Wolfram Physics model requires a set of rules, and an initial state:

```
myRule={{x, y}} -> {{x, y}, {y, z}};
myInitialState={{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
numberOfUpdates=5;

ResourceFunction[
  "WolframModel"][myRule, myInitialState, numberOfUpdates, "FinalStatePlot"]
```

Which gives us:

[image]

Which, as we can see, produces node-to-node connections, as in a "regular" network. So, what I'd like to know is if it's possible to have substitution rules that add edge-to-node connections, or even edge-to-edge! I've tried to do things like `myRule = {{x, y}\[DirectedEdge]{y, x}} -> {{x, y}, {y, z}}` but this currently does not work (the outputs of different trials are always node-to-node normal graphs).  Is this possible, even outside Wolfram Physics functions?

Thanks!

**Note**: There's no particular problem I need to solve. I just want to be able to introduce edge-to-node and edge-to-edge connections/substitutions in a graph, not just visualize these connections, but proper representation amenable to further analysis (e.g. check their connectivity, paths through them, etc.)

Comment: It would be rather helpful if you could provide more context and explanation what you are trying to achieve. 1) It is totally unclear to me how your problem is related to physics. 2) Could you somehow describe how your edge to node connections or edge to edge connections should look like and what they should describe. 3) Please give a simple (physics?) example of the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch 1) It is not related to physics (which also answers 3), just to "Wolfram Physics". 2) Nodes and edges are well represented in MMA, say ```VertexList[]```, or ```EdgeList[]```, so what I'm asking is a way to represent edges between these two types of objects, and even between edges. Final note: There's not a "problem" I need to solve, I just want to be able to do these types of representations. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about a rule on an edge. If you have two nodes on the LHS of your rule, you have an edge connecting them. If you then say how those two nodes transform, you are transforming the edges connecting those nodes as well. You have directed edges by virtue of the ordering of nodes (https://www.wolframphysics.org/technical-introduction/basic-form-of-models/basic-structure/) e.g. `{x,y}->{{x,y},{y,z}}` already splits the directed edge from x to y into two directed edges : one from x to y and one from y to z.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I'm not sure it does not make sense XD. I understand about the ordering and edge splitting that happens there, but why wouldn't be possible to add edge-to-edge rules? Say, make an edge between the ```{x,y}``` edge and the ```{y,z}``` edge, or variations of it (including removal of these, or edge-to-node edges). I don't think this generalization can be achieved with edge splitting alone.

Comment: Sounds like you are constructing a graph whose vertices are the vertices and edges of another graph. That seems to be relatively straightforward, no?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yep, that's my current roundabout way to do it, but I hope there's some generalization where I take these new edges as edges, not as nodes. More importantly, I hope the substitution rules can be generalized to take these edge rules as inputs for the replacements in Wolfram Physics style.

Comment: It seems like making an edge between edges would be equivalent to adding nodes in the middle of two edges and connecting those nodes. i.e. `{{x,y},{y,z}}->{{x,q},{q,y},{q,p},{y,p},{p,z}}`, where `q`, `p` split the `{x,y}`, `{y,z}` edges  and the new relations specify that you can only traverse that edge from the `{x,y}` edge to the `{y,z}` edge preserving the direction of each existing edge.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Yep, that seems equivalent, and very similar to what I'm currently doing. So, I'm just wondering how can it be done directly with edges as the objects, instead of adding these "fake nodes." But you could add that as an answer and I'll take a look. What I'm wondering for this solution is how would it be represented a rule that takes as inputs these edges; would you just keep track of the "q" nodes? What about edge-to-edge connections, and so on (edges on edges - to edges on edges)?

Comment: @TumbiSapichu I think you are adding node types. An edge from x to y could be `{x,y}` or `{x,x$y,y}`, where `x$y` is the edge node on `{x,y}`, which could connect to `y$z` in `{y,y$z,z}`. Then you'd need to specify how these things work. Does `x$y` exist by virtue of `{x,y}` existing, or does it need to be inserted? If `x` is deleted does `x$y` disappear? Can `x$y` connect to `z` directly or only to `y$z`? If you connect `{x$y,y$z}` can you have `{x$y,x$y$z,y$z}`, and how can `x$y$z` connect to other nth level nodes? You could write rules looking only for `{_$_,_$_}` nodes pretty easily.

Comment: @TumbiSapichu I think this is discussed in the last section of the wikipedia page on hypergraphs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph. "One possible generalization of a hypergraph is to allow edges to point at other edges." Which may give you some ideas.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Yeah, a general solution might require to involve hypergraphs :| Otherwise, it seems that some "smart labeling" scheme with regular nodes could suffice for simple(r) cases, as you point out. Hadn't thought of imposing a rule on edges might have secondary/side-effect "deletions" of nodes, but that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Your answer to my comment above is surprising, as it says in "The Wolfram Physics Project" chapter 8.2: "The basic concept of applying our models to physics is to imagine that the complete structure and content of the universe is represented by an evolving hypergraph."  So obviously you work on hypergraphs (as @N.J.Evans suggested) which should represent physics. At least a clue on what you envisage would be useful

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch I'm trying to represent transformations of things in an abstract sense. Say thing A becomes thing B, given a constraint: A --constraintAB-->B, the constraint being the edge. Then, I want to add an edge such as constraintAB----constraintX--->C, and so on. That would mean being able to add an edge between an edge (constraintAB) and a "thing" C, and so on. So, that's as clear as a clue of what I envision, because it has no practical purpose so far. The Wikipedia article on hypergraphs mention this extension, but gives no practical clue to me, not within my math or MMA expertise.